# 'Project.API.Hubs.ChatHub.OnDisconnected()': no suitable method found to override

Tags: asp.net, signalr

```
public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    var name = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value ==    Context.ConnectionId.ToString());
    string s;
    dic.TryRemove(name.Key, out s);
    return Clients.All.disconnected(name.Key);
}
```

I don't know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

They changed signature of the method in SignalR 2.1

It now looks like

```
 public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
```

Comment: Thank u..By using signalr how to show to online usersnames in asp.net web form...do u have any idea about that?

Comment: I got the same question on my blog the other day, my answer http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/05/27/client-server-event-aggregation-with-signalr/comment-page-1/#comment-167. I also made an example for him found here https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/ConnectionStateExample